# How to compare data between two different database of two different providers?

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison, migration

We are planning to do a database Migration from MySql Server to MSSQL server; we have got some external tools and some internal tools to accomplish this. Now we need to have a process to validate the data between the MySql and MSSQL server after the Migration. We did a search and came across tablediff.exe. But it seems it can compare between only MSSQL databases. Not sure if we can use this tools by creating a linked server for MySql database (If so please let me know how to do that). If there is any other tools please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using Linked server option of mssql server. I have created the linked server for my mysql database and used following query to achieve this

```
(select * from a 
except select * openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select * from a'))
Union
(select * openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select * from a')
except 
select * from a)
```

I'm not sure if this is a right way of doing this. But it did worked for us.